# Bootstrap tooltip wrong position on svg element when page is scrolled down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg, tooltip

I have problem with Bootstrap (3.3.7) **tooltips** for **svg elements**. Tooltips working well when page is scrolled to the top. But whenever i scroll page down, tooltips have wrong vertical position (the more i scroll down the page,  the distance between tootltip and tooltiped element is larger).

Here is a basic example with mentioned problem (there is also test button with tooltip which working well):

HTML:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="top-wrap"></div>
  <div class="svg-wrap">
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle id="svg-el" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
    </svg> 
  </div>

  <button id="test-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Tooltip on left</button>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#svg-el').tooltip({
        'container': '.svg-wrap',
        'placement': 'top',
        'html':'true',
        'title': '<strong class="text-uppercase">France</strong><br/> example html content.'
    });
  $('#test-button').tooltip({
        'container': 'body',
        'placement': 'top',
        'title': 'Example tooltip.'
    });
});
```

See working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crnjrdbo/3/) .

Can someone help me or have someone the same problem? I tried many options for tooltip but I'm not able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate on @gabel's answer, for fixing bootstrap v3.3.7,

- go to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/js/tooltip.js
- look for the declaration of Tooltip.getPosition: `Tooltip.prototype.getPosition = function ($element) {`
- The offending lines are:
  `var isSvg = window.SVGElement && el instanceof window.SVGElement`
  and
  `var elOffset  = isBody ? { top: 0, left: 0 } : (isSvg ? null : $element.offset())`

As you can see, the positioning is deliberately disabled for SVGs. So enable it, by forcibly setting `isSvg` to false: `var isSvg = false`

If you're working with the minified version of bootstrap, it is relatively easy to search & replace by looking for `getPosition`'s prototype declaration as well. The `isSvg` variable is obfuscated, but should be around there as well.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered exactly the same annoying bug, and didn't manage to find any solution.
However, what seemed more reasonable to me is to get around this bug by wrapping that `<svg>` with an ordinary HTML element like `<div>`, and set tooltip on that `<div>`.

```
$('.svg-wrap').tooltip({
    'container': 'body',
    'placement': 'top',
    'html':'true',
    'title': '<strong class="text-uppercase">France</strong><br/> example html content.'
});
```

Comment: Thanks this saved me.

Answer (score 3):

In Bootstrap 3.3.5 this is still working.

`Change JS resource to https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js`

https://jsfiddle.net/gabel/crnjrdbo/5/

Comment: I would give you more votes, if I could. This saved me heaps of time. Using 3.3.7, overwriting the `getPosition` method with the old version.